# Experiencing CLR error on SQL Azure DB

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-clr

Out of nowhere we started seeing this error and it seems to occur fairly frequently when making calls to the database or any other database in our Elastic Pool. The DTUs aren't being maxed out and the resource dmvs don't seem bad.

> Failed to enter Common Language Runtime (CLR) with HRESULT 
>   0x80131022. This may be due to low resource conditions. (db)

Here's what I got from the system resource governor pool

```
Resource Pool Name           cache_memory (MB)   used_memory (MB)
internal                     104.773437          1577.125000
default                      37.609375           38.796875
SloSecSharedPool             2.914062            8.156250
InMemBackupRestorePool       26.210937           101.437500
InMemDmvCollectorPool        186.195312          203.406250
InMemMetricsDownloaderPool   2.234375            2.250000
InMemDTAPool                 0.000000            0.000000
SloHkPool                    0.000000            0.031250
InMemQueryStorePool          22.453125           35.304687
InMemWIAutoTuningPool        3.312500            4.062500
InMemXdbLoginPool            3.976562            6.250000
PVSCleanerPool               0.000000            0.000000
InMemTdeScanPool             0.000000            0.000000
SloSharedPool1               1108.890625         1234.312500
```

From the sys.dm_os_performance_counters this is what it looks like for the past 3 hours.

```
cpu%    data_io%   log_write%   memory_usage%   max_worker%   sessions%
22.37   73.51      16.54        41.56           5.50          0.43
```

This doesn't seem like a common error for SQL Azure as I cannot find anything that pertains to this happening past SQL Server 2008. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

We got a response from the Microsoft support rep and it looks like our memory usage was completely capped out.

[image: Elastic Pool resource usage]

After moving the elastic pool up a tier the error has gone away. We have ~56GB of memory instead of the ~28GB we had previously and the error ceased. This would have probably also moved us to a different server on Azure which may have fixed the problem for now. The site has been running at around 78% on memory usage with the buffer cache hit ratio @ 8588 and PLE of 87332. Now it's operating at usage under 2% across the board for CPU, Workers, DataIO, etc. during normal load which seems like a huge waste.

We could not definitively identify what was causing the errors but we assume it was the complete memory usage as the site is running fine for now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Azure SQL Database (*not* the new Managed Instance) does not support custom SQLCLR Assemblies (i.e. the "CLR enabled" server-level configuration option), CLR is still used internally for the following features:

1. CLR datatypes:

   - Geometry
   - Geography
   - Hierarchyid
2. Built-in functions:

   - introduced in SQL Server 2012:

     - `FORMAT`
     - `PARSE`
     - `TRY_PARSE`
   - introduced in SQL Server 2016:

     - `AT TIME ZONE`
     - `COMPRESS`
     - `DECOMPRESS`
     - `sys.time_zone_info`
   - maybe others
3. SSIS (Fuzzy Lookup / `sp_FuzzyLookupTableMaintenanceInvoke`, etc)
4. Change Data Capture (CDC)
5. Replication
6. Master Data Services
7. Policy Based Managemen (PBM; originally named "Dynamic Management Framework (DMF)" )
8. External Tables (including External Data Sources and possibly External File Formats): This functionality is new as of SQL Server 2016, and this functionality using CLR internally has been mentioned in other answers here by Joe and Henrik. Both Joe and Henrik indicate being told by Microsoft that External Tables rely upon CLR, and while I have not been able to confirm this directly (by seeing the system App Domain get created when using any of this functionality), I was at least able to confirm that when "Lightweight Pooling" mode is enabled, all 3 of these components fail with the following error:

   > Msg 7432, Level 16, State 0, Line XXXXX
   >   Heterogeneous queries and use of OLEDB providers are not supported in fiber mode.
9. maybe others

Of course, this does not point to what *would* be hogging memory. But it should help identify the affected area(s).

Comment: Do you know if Extended Events are using CLR? We had the CLR too, and at a time where I've been trying to set up a new Event, with a large buffer.

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen Hi there. No, I am not aware of whether or not Extended Events uses the CLR in any way. But I would guess not since nothing CLR based works when "lightweight pooling" (i.e. fiber mode) is enabled, and I can't imagine Extended Events not functioning.

Comment: According to Microsoft, External Tables are using CLR. I tried to update your post, but it was rejected by mustaccio and McNets because "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more acc".
Just to let you know that there is currently a known bug with external tables, and it causes my sql to report the CLR error every two weeks or so.

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen I have done some testing and have updated my answer based on the results. Thanks for mentioning this! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using Azure SQL DB (not managed instance) and it most definitely uses the CLR for things like geo-spatial and `AT TIME ZONE`

I have been having this same problem and could not find a solution.  [Working with MS support and this is what we came up with as a possible resolution - just did it 10 minutes ago, but seems legit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dbd30dc-15f9-4ec0-8dac-9feae2c32aa5/clr-error-on-azure-sql-db?forum=ssdsgetstarted#7dbd30dc-15f9-4ec0-8dac-9feae2c32aa5):

> The hypothesis is that the CLR errors we have been experiencing are
>   due to the use of external tables which leverage the CLR (via elastic
>   search). The external table implementation has been corrupting CLR
>   threads and is under investigation by Microsoft.
>
> I was only using external tables for some operational maintenance, so
>   I was able to drop those.  I then had to reset the databases to reset
>   all the threads.  There is an undocumented DBCC command to do this:
>
> ```
> dbcc stackdump('')
> ```
>
> This takes down your database and then it fails over to another
>   redundant server. When I ran that, there was about a 5 second outage

Answer (score 2):

As you can read on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information) documentation, CLR is not supported on Azure SQL Database. However, the new [Azure Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance) does support CLR.

Comment: Thank you for providing those resources. I read through and we don't actually use anything CLR related.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this error, I ran this query in the master database:

```
select DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, rs.start_time), 0) as hr, max(avg_instance_memory_percent) as MaxMem 
from sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats rs
group by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, rs.start_time), 0)
order by 1
```

It showed that the max memory had gone to 100% in the hours prior to the error.
So now I run it on a schedule, and I get a warning if it goes over 95%.
Then I can schedule a restart of the Azure SQL database outside office hours, or get Microsoft to look at it, before everything stops working.

**Unfortunately** it has turned out that the error is **not totally related** to memory usage. I opened a case with Microsoft, and was told that there are currently a problem with External Tables (which is currently just in preview/beta)

I think I'll just start running the PowerShell command Invoke-AzSqlDatabaseFailover on a schedule.